# Does the amount of free space on a HDD have an effect on power consumption?

Tags: hard-drive, email, power, power-consumption

I a couple of friends on Facebook have started spreading a message stating that if you delete 30 old E-Mails from your inbox it would save enough power to light a light bulb for 24 hours.

They also put a link to this page http://fullmobs.org/mobilisation/r%C3%A9solution-2016-du-balai-les-vieux-emails-depollutionnumerique (I don't understand French but I couldn't find any sources of where this came from).

My question is thus, does the amount of free space on a HDD have any effect on power consumption?

As far as my searching has come up with an HDD basically uses the same amount of power regardless of amount of free space. In face it would most likely consume more power if a lot of people went and deleted E-Mail from their inbox it would since it would activate HDDs that were currently hibernating or in some kind of low energy state since it would trigger a read/write to the HDD.

Any help to debunk/confirm this would be much appreciated.

Sincerely
duxck

Comment: They would actually save more energy if they deleted their Facebook accounts entirely

Comment: I honestly just considered doing the math to prove it wasn't true, then considered how much energy it would waste. No. 30 emails is barely any space at all. If it were true, delete a single video and you've just solved the worlds energy problems.

Comment: The email you received is called a chain letter, in most cases 99.99999% of the time, the information contained in such a letter is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Free space on a hard drive has nothing to do with power consumption.  Whether the hard drive is a tradition magnetic hard drive, or a modern solid state disk, the data on the hard drive requires no power to be maintained once written to disk.

In reality, the act of deleting a file will *consume* more power, as the computer has to do work to accomplish the task.  Granted, that amount of power is extremely minuscule.  It is no different than writing on paper with a pencil.  Once written, it is there permanently, however *erasing* it requires work.

There are a lot of ways to [reduce computer power usage](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=reducing%20computer%20power%20consumption), however that Facebook message is false.

Answer (score 0):

On non ssd drives yes, though the effect may not be large. A hard drive which is fairly full will tend to have free space which is heavily fragmented. Consequently write operations will require more head moves and more power. Read operations on files written during low free space conditions will also be affected. Reads of files written when the drive was clean all not be.